# how to match value and then use if function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to create a third table, where I could first return the common numbers between two available tables - this part is easy.. vlookup works fine.

The next step is to compare whether the values in ER, SR, SM, EC columns are similar based on the fact that they have the same key in column "Number"

[image]

For this purpose, I am trying to build - if(vlookup or iferror formulas - but I don't really get it.

Ideally, third table should look like:

```
                            ER    SR   SM   EC
```

e.g. number 100002 (in 2nd row) False True True False

ER and EC return false because the values are different in two tables, while SR and SM return True as values are the same (both NULL).

I would appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "third table " starts at T2 cell.. where T1 is "number", U1 is "ER",V1 is "SR",W1 is "SM",X1 is "EC". Also assuming that you will have the "number" values filled up.

put in U2 `=if(index(B:B,match($T2,$A:$A,0))=index(L:L,match($T2,$K:$K,0)),TRUE,FALSE)`

then drag it to the right + downwards.

Comment: It actually worked, thank you for sharing this formula!


However, I showed this to my manager, and he wants more granularity now... So, I came up with the following formula: IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(U10,K:L,2,FALSE)),"Miss",(IF(VLOOKUP(U10,A:B,2,FALSE)="NULL","Add",IF(VLOOKUP(U10,A:B,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(U10,K:L,2,FALSE),"Ok","UNKNOWN CONDITION"))))   -> However, it does not satisfy all the conditions. If values show NULL for the same number in both tables - it doesn't return "OK"  instead I am getting back "Add". 

I wonder if you might have an idea why it's happening.

Comment: What do you mean by  "granularity" ? Any Example? || btw if this really IS another question.. I think it should be either : (a) update the details in the question above. or (b) start a new question. || Fyi, you may click the 'tick' mark beside this solution if at had answered your original question. ( :

Comment: " However, it does not satisfy all the conditions. If values show NULL for the same number in both tables " -> would you mind sharing the full sample data? couldn't see what you mean without one.. ||  it doesn't return "OK" instead I am getting back "Add". -> Which cell are you referring to? (^_^)